# How to replace the datasource by the processed result in same glue task

Tags: python-3.x, scala, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I want to process some data from A and replace A by the processed result.

Is there any "place" I can do something after a write() action completed? or is there a way to replace original dir to make sure only the final result in it?

And btw, will there any side effect if I write the result into same dir of data sources I read?

My current program logic (with bug) looks like below:

1. Read data from s3://bucket-A/some-path-to-object
2. Use `spark.sql()` to process some aggregation
3. Read data from s3://bucket-B/1970/01/01/00
4. Using `spark.sql()` to FULL JOIN result and pick the col I need (schema will not changed)
5. Write result back to s3://bucket-B/1970/01/01/00 with overwrite mode

and I ran the code in AWS Glue 4.0, with Spark 3.3, Scala 2 and Python 3

I already know all I did are generate a DAG, and only when write() is called, the process will start, and if I use the `overwrite` mode, the source data will removed before I read them.

Even though I can create an new s3 object in same parent path, I'm not able to remove the old one to keep result unique.

Answer (score 1):

I would generally stay away from overwriting directly as in case of an intermediate failure you would lose the old and new data and you will have some Spark intermediate files starting with a period that you cannot really use.

Also, smaller datasets may work with reading and writing to the same location, as spark temp intermediate files will overwrite the original files in one shot at the end. But larger datasets may have multiple intermediate writes . This may cause a circular reference issue as Spark does not keep track on which data was already processed.

In my opinion, use a temporary directory for intermediate processing, copy from temporary directory to s3://bucket-B/1970/01/01/00 and delete the temporary directory

```
shutil.rmtree(temp_dir)
```